# TCP send takes a long time

Tags: sockets, tcp, system-calls, send, strace

This problem occurs in a proxy server,and the code is

```
gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
sendLen = ::send(connection->Fd(), buffer->rdPtr, wantSendLen, 0);
gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
uint64_t send_buf_cost = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec);
LOGGER_LOG(m_logger, "send time:%lu", send_buf_cost);
```

the send call occasionally takes more than 50ms in log , when fd is a  NON_BLOCK socket and wantSendLen is less than 200 bytes.

after that, I use strace to prove it

> strace -o output.txt -T -tt -e trace=network -p 15550

and I can find the long time call like this

> 14:14:31.510672 sendto(49,
>   "*2\r\n$3\r\nget\r\n$88\r\nmsgpool:fgmsg:"..., 108, 0, NULL, 0) = 108
>   <0.068225>

why the send call is sometimes so slow ? I think the send call is only doing data copy to socket send buffer.